# How to remove empty element in an array

Tags: php

I have been trying array_filter but doesn't work on my part.

[image]

Comment: why didn't you check for _null_ before adding item into array?

Comment: When asking questions be more programmatic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want is to remove empty arrays inside an array, you can use this

```
$array= array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array));
```